# How to encounter reply when user attaches a document/image to a chatbot(Build with dialogflow and kommunicate)?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, kommunicate

I have tried many different methods but it is not working properly.Please any one can help me how to send a reply when user uploads any attachments in a chatbot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to achieve your objective, it is important to understand what dialogflow events are: Events allow you to invoke intents based on something that has happened instead of what a user communicates. Dialogflow supports events from several platforms (like Google Assistant, Slack, and more) based on actions users take on those platforms.

When a user attaches a file or shares location, Kommunicate sends a custom event `KOMMUNICATE_MEDIA_EVENT` to your bot along with the attached file information. To have an `upload intent` respond to the `KOMMUNICATE_MEDIA_EVENT`, follow these steps to create this custom event in your dialogflow bot:

**How to add an event to an intent**

1. Go to the Events section of the intent.
2. Type the name of the event you'd like your intent to respond to (`KOMMUNICATE_MEDIA_EVENT`).
3. Press enter.
4. Click SAVE.

Also remember to add your response that the bot will deliver to a user when they upload a document.

**References:**

1. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-overview
2. https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-custom-integration#send-attachments-to-bot
3. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/build-agent

I hope this helps?